# Alternate sync-nonsync blocks in java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have a question about synchronized blocks and multithreading. I have an "alternate" situation in which two synchronized blocks should be executed before and after a non-synchronized block, and such blocks should not interfere each other.

Here is (a portion of) the code:

```
boolean calculate = false;    

synchronized(this){
    Double oldSim = struct.get(pair);

    if(oldSim == null || oldSim < maxThreshold)
        calculate = true;
}

if(calculate)
{
    // This part should be parallel
    Double newSim = calculateSimilarity(...);

    synchronized(this){
        if(newSim > minThreshold && (oldSim == null || newSim > oldSim))
            struct.put(pair, newSim);
    }
}
```

The problem is that, in this way, different threads could execute the first sync block, while another thread could execute the second sync block. So, I though this solution:

```
int maxThreshold = 1.0;

if(checkAndwriteSimilarity(pair, null, false))
{
    Double newSim = calculateSimilarity(table, pKey1, pKey2, pKey1Val, pKey2Val, c);
    checkAndwriteSimilarity(pair, newSim, true);
}

private synchronized boolean checkAndwriteSimilarity(Pair pair, Double newSim, boolean write)
{
    Double oldSim = struct.get(pair);
    if(!write)
    {
        if(oldSim == null || oldSim < maxThreshold)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
    {
        if(newSim > minThreshold && (oldSim == null || newSim > oldSim))
            struct.put(pair, newSim);
        return true;
    }       
}
```

Do you think it is the most correct solution? I sincerely do not like such method a lot ... 
Do you have alternative solutions to suggest?

Thank you

Comment: Seems reasonable to me if you want to be able to run the calculate in parallel it is possible you have updated the key already.

Comment: don't use `synchronized(this)` i will do nothing because each theard is it's own synchronized object

Comment: What do you mean by "different threads could execute... *while* another thread could execute"? Only one `synchronized` block can be active at any time on a particular object; multiple different `synchronized` blocks don't run in parallel.

Comment: So you want to make sure that one thread enters the first synchronized block, and then the _same_ thread enters the second synchronized block even though it's ok if other threads now enter the first block? What kind of craziness dictates this requirement?

Comment: I use Runnable interface, so there is just one single object. If chrylis is right, then I should not have any interference between different synchronized blocks.

Comment: Your first example isn't even compilable - oldSim is declared inside the first synchronized block, but is used in the second block. By the way the only way that "another thread could execute the second sync block" is if it first executed the first block; I really don't see the problem.